# Full Text Search Strategy For My Website - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-design, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I have a website that allows users to search for items in various categories. Each category is a separate area (page) of my website. For example, some categories might be cars, bikes, books etc. At the moment a user has to search for an item by going to the page (for example, cars) and searching for the car they want. I would like to allow the user to search for anything on my site, from my main home page.

At the moment, each page (category) has its own set of tables, and I don't really want to turn Full Text Search on for each table (20+ of them) and search each table individually when a search is done. This is going to be slow and tedious.

What I'm thinking of doing is creating a single table that will hold all searchable information for each category of item (when an item is saved in its respective table, I would copy all searchable information over to my 'Search' table). I would then turn Full Text Search on for that table, and search that table.

Does this sound reasonable? Is there a better way? I've never used Full Text Search before, so this is new to me.

One comment. The schema I've described here is vastly 'dumbed down' to make the concept of the question easier to understand.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable approach. The alternative is to run 20+ separate full text searches and combine the results, which is nearly impossible to do right considering how they'll all be ranked differently.

Answer (score -1):

I'd read this article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx it appears that you are taking a long way to do something you have to do to set up full text search anyway: ie full text seach only occurs (effectively) against tables and columns that have explicitly been indexed. simply "turning on" full text search does not do this. Oh and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx